# Find the line that change the scroll position

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a page where the scroll is set back to neutral (0) when I come back to it (it should instead get back to position I were when I left the page). I am using chrome, is there a way to find what line of javascript changes the scroll position when I land on the page? (There is too many javascript in the project to simply review the code)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It will get set to 0 if the content inside is loaded dynamically. In this case it is not set by your JS, you have to implement the "scroll back to last position" by yourself with JS.

Comment: @cloned Ok, I think my question was not clear enough. I have a page that got the scrolltop set to 0, I need to identify what line is responsible of that (in a bunch of hundred of thousand of lines of code/js files) like the break option in chrome dev tool.

Comment: For me it's still not clearer, you just repeated what you wrote in the actual question. Search through all the files or listen to event handlers. That are your two options.

Comment: there were a third before recent chrome version, it was creating a breakpoint for scrolling events. But now, I can't find where did they put this option